# jQuery Validate - Get value from select and based on the value make text input required field

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I have a form with a select with 3 options "Blank", "Yes" and "No". I also have a text input which is part of this situation.

My HTML is as follows (Extract):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
   <select class="form-control" id="medical" name="medical" onchange=" if(this.value == 'medyes') { document.getElementById('medcon-text').style.display = 'block'; } else { document.getElementById('medcon-text').style.display = 'none';} ">
    <option value="Select an option"></option>
    <option value="medyes">Yes</option>
    <option value="medno">No</option>
   </select>
  </div>
<!--close medical select--> 
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
     <div id="medcon-text" style="display:none;">
       <label class="control-label">If so please specify:</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="medicaltext" name="medicaltext" placeholder="Enter your disability or medical condition">
     </div>
   </div>
   <!--close medical condition--> 
 </div>
 <!--close row-->
```

jQuery Validate Code (Extract):

```
$("#online-application").validate({


    rules: {
        medical: {
            required: true
        },
        medcon: {
            required: $("#medical").val() == "medyes"
        },
    },

    messages: {
        medical: "Please select an option.",
        medicaltext: "Please enter your medical condition.",
    },
```

My question is, how do I make the select a required field and IF the select value is "Yes"/"medyes" then make the medicaltext input a required field. However, if the select value is no or blank then the medicaltext input must NOT be required.

Comment: Please check the documentation for the `depends` property of the `rules` option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a `function()` that returns `true/false` in conjunction with the `depends` property.

```
rules: {
    medical: {
        required: true
    },
    medicaltext: { // <- NAME attribute of the input
        required: {
            depends: function() {
                return ($("#medical").val() == "medyes");
            }
        }  
    },
},
```

Within the `.validate()` method, rules can only be assigned using the `name` attribute of each input element.  Since I don't see any input with `name="medcon"`, then this needs to be changed to match the `name` on the text input element.

See documentation for `depends`:  [jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#rules](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#rules)

---

For `required` to work on a `select`, you also need to change this line...

```
<option value="Select an option"></option>
```

into this...

```
<option value="">Select an option</option>
```

---

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/34oo7nrg/**

Comment: With regards to your edit, I saw that as I was going through my code. Thanks again.